# nltk in python to extract information from web page

Tags: import, nltk

how can I use nltk in python to extract information from web page (job offers in my case)

I use this code to extract a part of text ,

```
import nltk
import time
import urllib2 
from urllib2 import urlopen 
from cookielib import CookieJar 
import datetime


website = "http://tanitjobs.com/search-results-jobs/"
topSplit = "<div class=\"offre\">"
ButtomSplit = "<div class=\"offre-emploi&nbsp;\">"
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('Uer-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

def main():

    try:

        ss =opener.open(website).read()
        sourceCodeSplit = ss.split(topSplit)[1].split(ButtomSplit)[0]
        texte = nltk.clean_html(sourceCodeSplit)
        print texte
    except Exception,e:
        print 'fail in the main loop'
        print str(e)


main()
```

but I don't know how to do it if I would  extract specific paragraph (job offers) from a web page in general

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, sadly, there is no one way to crawl pages and extract a specific section. have fun crawling/cleaning

Comment: thanks "alvas". can you give me some examples to start ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will need `urllib.request` from python3, see http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html

Next, BeautifulSoup is your friend: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. I find this useful in installing bs4 in py3.x see http://annelagang.blogspot.fr/2012/11/beautifulsoup-4-for-python-3x.html

Here's a working example:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
url="http://tanitjobs.com/search-results-jobs/"

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()

for i in bs(data).find_all(attrs={"class": "offre-emploi vedette"}):
    print(" ".join(i.find("div",attrs={"class":"detail"}).text.split()))
    print
```

**[out]:**

> Téléopérateurs (trices) Quality Com Center QualityCom sis a
>   Montplaisir recrute des téléopérateurs (trices), en... Voir toutes les
>   offres de Quality Com Center
>
> Contrôleur de gestion Eureka Developpement Humain Pour le compte d’une
>   Multinationale dans le domaine de l'industrie, nous recrutons un :...
>   Voir toutes les offres de Eureka Developpement Humain
>
> Responsable ressources humaines (H/F) Eureka Developpement Humain Pour
>   son propre compte Eureka Développement Humain Recrute : Responsable...
>   Voir toutes les offres de Eureka Developpement Humain
>
> Contrôleur Financier Junior Proxy Tunisie Rattaché au Directeur
>   Administratif et Financier pays, votre rôle est de garantir la
>   gestion... Voir toutes les offres de Proxy Tunisie
>
> Superviseur en prise de rdv ( énergie renouvelable ) Quality Com
>   Center Quality Com Center sis a Montplaisir Recrute 1 Superviseur(e)
>   en Panneaux... Voir toutes les offres de Quality Com Center
>
> Téléconseillers (h/f) Axess global services AXESS GLOBAL SERVICES
>   Recrutement Vous souhaitez travailler dans une Enterprise jeune et...
>   Voir toutes les offres de Axess global services

Comment: I use python 2.7 ; there is no "urllib.request" module : (

Comment: only python3 allows you to use user-agent header. if you're just scraping the site, use py3.x then use py2.x to process other stuff.

Comment: I used "urllib2" and it returned the same result : )